# When creating a 'Checkboxes' question in Google Spreadsheets, what formula do I use to add a mark to each box ticket correct to the answer?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am creating a Google Spreadsheet for the first time and I have suddenly become stuck.

When filling out my spreadsheet I do not know what formula to use when adding up the correct answers.

I have included an example below (all the answers are correct, however if my student only selects one, I still want to give them a mark to each allocated tick)

[image]

The syntax I am currently working on is:

```
=if(L2="Return all unused pins back into the plastic kits.", "1", "0")+(L2="Use fabric scissors when cutting  fabric.", "1", "0")+(L2="Position the sewing machine close to you when you are working", "1", "0")+(L2="Return all equipment back to where it belongs.", "1", "0")+(L2="Place your work inside the CORRECTLY labeled class tub.", "1", "0")+(L2="Turn iron off at power point", "1", "0")+(L2="Push chairs under desk when leaving work station", "1", "0")+(L2="Use polite manners at all times.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want to do in your example is to count the number of options ticked.

In the spreadsheet receiving the form responses, each response is assigned to a row. The answers to your security questions are assigned to a cell in that row, apparently `L2`, judging by your formula example.
If a student selects, say, the first two options, the `L2` cell will be `Return all unused pins back into the plastic kits., Use fabric scissors when cutting fabric.`. That is, the text of the selected options, separated by `,` (a comma and a space).

Knowing that, we can put the following formula in another cell in that row (for example in `M2`):

```
=SPLIT(L2; ", "; FALSE)
```

This will expand the contents of `L2`, splitting the string up by the `,` separator, so that each checked option will occupy its own cell:

```
| L2                                                 | M2                      | N2                        | O2 | ... |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return all unused (...), Use fabric scissors (...) | Return all unused (...) | Use fabric scissors (...) |    |
```

... which is not exactly what we want, since we just want to know the *number of* checked options, but we can learn that by wrapping the formula in a `COUNTA` function:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(L2; ", "; FALSE))
```

... which will return `2`.

Feel free to copy [the spreadsheet I set up to demonstrate](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15wlzVuRY2iej4Y_aO4rHu0ipnN9t1AtjlOjTUIZisZY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you possibly help with with my next problem too??

Comment: This time i am trying to calculate the number of correct answers.
Eg: Option 1 -Correct,
      Option 2 - Incorrect, 
      Option 3 - Correct.

The Students need to tick the check boxes, but i still want to award them a mark for each correct answer chosen.


Thanks so much for your help on my last question, i has stuck on that for a few days. haha

Comment: You should post that as a separate question, with a link to this question.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86836/when-using-google-spreadsheets-what-syntax-do-i-use-to-add-up-the-correct-answe