# How to add up the correct answers from the check boxes question?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

What syntax do I use when adding up the number of **correct answers** that have boxes checked?

My question is;[image]

In this example the correct answers are Cotton and Calico.
I award the students a total of 2 marks ( 1 mark each) in selected. Therefore if a student selects Denim, Satin or Silk, they do not get a mark.

The current Syntax I have been using is something along the lines of;

```
=if(D2="Cotton.", "1", "0", "Calico.", "1", "0", "Demin.", "0", "0", "Satin.", "0", "0", "Silk.", "0", "0")
```

Comment: For thos eof you who might be looking at the other side of the question this answer was great help ;
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/when-creating-a-checkboxes-question-in-google-spreadsheets-what-formula-do-i

Comment: So, if a student selects all five boxes, do they get full credit (2 points) as well? That seems wrong.

Comment: @NormalHuman, The students are only allowed to select 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

Two more to try:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(split(D2,","), "Cotton|Calico")))
```

or

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(countif(D2, {"*Cotton*", "*Calico*"})))
```

Answer (score 0):

The responses are recorded in the comma-space separated format, e.g., `Calico, Silk`. Suppose that the response is in cell B2: then the following formula gives the number of correctly checked boxes:

```
=countif(arrayformula(regexmatch(split(B2,", "), "^(Cotton|Calico)$")), TRUE)
```

Explanation:

- `split(B2,", ")` splits the string into an array of responses
- `arrayformula(regexmatch(..., "^(Cotton|Calico)$"))` processes the responses, returning TRUE if it's correct.
- `countif(... TRUE)` counts the number of TRUE results.

If the correct answers are stored in, say, cells E2:E3, then the formula becomes

```
=countif(arrayformula(regexmatch(split(B2,", "), "^("&join("|", E2:E3)&")$")), TRUE)
```